# java method call on multiple objects

Tags: java, object, initialization, method-call

I installed a plugin for eclipse that helps creating a JFrame in a UI.
The code generated form the plugin has some strange syntax.
I never ever saw something like this in java:

```
private JPanel b_,cb_,pb_,l_,tf_,ta_contentPane;

public Mainf() {
    b_,cb_,pb_,l_,tf_,ta_contentPane = new JPanel();
    b_,cb_,pb_,l_,tf_,ta_contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    b_,cb_,pb_,l_,tf_,ta_contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(b_,cb_,pb_,l_,tf_,ta_contentPane);
}
```

how is that even possible? ^^
The standard java compiler sees that as a syntax error.
Is there a option to compile this right?

**Edit:**
I found it again (^^). All of these tools use this syntax.
URL for Eclipse: Help->Install new Software...

> WindowBuilder Pro Eclipse Update Site - http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.3/

and the Website:

> http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

Comment: It looks like the comma is supposed to be part of the variable name as opposed to a list, maybe? So you could potentially search+replace with _ or something.

Alternatively, you can install a better plugin.

Comment: are you saying it is compiled in your eclipse with out errors?

Comment: can't you change variable name? like in matisse?

Comment: Please provide the plugin name.  (I'm sure other people will be able to help you better with that information; I just want to know to avoid it. :D)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no option to compile that right.

```
private JPanel b_,cb_,pb_,l_,tf_,ta_contentPane;
```

Is a correct sentence.

```
b_,cb_,pb_,l_,tf_,ta_contentPane = new JPanel();
b_,cb_,pb_,l_,tf_,ta_contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
b_,cb_,pb_,l_,tf_,ta_contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
```

Are incorrect sencences.

Comment: Yeah, I think OP already figured that part out. Question is: why did the plugin generate that code, and how to fix it.

Comment: You might also want to explain what the "correct sentence" means. Most likely it is *not* what the OP wants, nor what the plugin meant to generate.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct but the variable name generated is a not a valid identifier. The solution is to rename the variable and the code will compile fine.

```
private JPanel contentPane;

public Mainf() {
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
}
```

Comment: but then the b_,cb_,pb_,l_ and tf_ JPanels wouldn't exist ^^. The JFrame Builder seems to need those JPanels.

Comment: If the JFrame is expecting 6 JPanels instead of 1 then this is not a valid syntax. You can declare many variables on one line by separating them with comma, but initilizing more than one variable with a comma separation is not a legal syntax.